# Is there any way to subclass a class, using a subclass of the classes subclass?

Tags: kotlin, javafx

Sorry for the nonsensical title, I have no idea how to describe this question.

Let's say I create `class NodeWithExtraProperty: Node(), Weighted`, where `Node` is some class I can't modify.

Is there any way I can create a `WeightedButton: Button(), Weighted`, where `Button` is a subclass of `Node`? The WeightedButton would only be used in an `out` position.

I want to create some UI classes (e.g., Buttons) that can be displayed anywhere a Node can, but has some extra properties and functions specified by an interface. Button is already a subclass of Node, but I can't figure out how to declare the class in this case.

Comment: In general, you achieve something like this using a decorator pattern. However, in this case, that won't work because the `Node` hierarchy is not designed with that pattern in mind (specifically, some methods you would need to override would not be accessible). This just seems like the wrong approach to whatever problem you are trying to solve at some other level. I basically never subclass `Node` classes (with the exception of those specifically designed for subclasses, such as cells).

Comment: @James_D I want to display a List<ToolbarItems>, where ToolbarItems can be anything that can be displayed, i.e., a Node. The controls might be Button, ToggleButton, radio buttons, etc. But the controls have some extra information (in the interface) that is used to determine their ordering. I originally had a `val content: Node` rather than subclassing Node, but I'd like to be able to use Node functions, like `isVisible` directly on the items, rather than item.content

Comment: This just sounds like a horrible design. You're trying to store elements of the data you're displaying (e.g. the ordering) in the nodes themselves, which violates pretty much every fundamental principle of UI code design.

Comment: Just in general; work with the API the way it's designed to be used, instead of trying to fight against it.

Comment: Where would be a better place to store the order?

Comment: In your model class. JavaFX is really designed to be used with a MVC-type design.

Comment: In that case, isn't the toolbar isn't the toolbar the controller, and the list of weighted items being passed in are the model?

Comment: A toolbar is a visual component, so it’s a View. Any subclass of a Node is similarly a view.